# Windows Server 2003 DNS not resolving internal and external domains for clients

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to setup an AD Domain in Amazon's EC2 Cloud. I have several EC2 instances running inside a VPC. Security Groups are configured to allow all traffic from the subnet the instances are on.

I have a server (AwsAdmin1) setup as the DNS server. Running NSLOOKUP on AwsAdmin1 works perfectly, and it can access the internet. It is set to use its internal IP as the Primary DNS server.

The server I setup to test the DNS (AwsTest1) is set to use AwsAdmin1 as the primary DNS. Running NSLOOKUP returns the error, "Can't find the server name for address: 10.1.1.4 (AwsAdmin1's IP): Timed Out

Trying to ping AwsAdmin1 by name times out

AwsAdmin1 CAN be pinged BY IP

AwsAdmin1 has a A Name and a PTR record on itself

Running WireShark shows that DNS traffic from AwsTest1 reaches AwsAdmin1

The primary DNS suffix for both of the servers is imkamzn.public.com (Fake address here, obviously, but it is a routable address)

These computers are NOT in a domain currently. Trying to get the DNS running first before I setup AD.

What could be causing these issues? I suspect it has to do with the DNS suffix, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip:

Uninstall the DNS role and let it be installed as part of the DCPROMO process. That's going to insure that it's installed and configured correctly and that it's going to function properly as a DNS server in support of your AD domain.